# Parsing URI stored in local storage on device to ImageView

Tags: android, imageview, uri

I'm creating the app where i have to display multiple URI's the user has chosen from their own images, currently i'm just trying to display one:

Current code:
(TouchImageView is just a library i'm used that works exactly like imageview)

```
TouchImageView img = (TouchImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
img.setImageURI(Uri.parse("file://storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/1411724483755.jpg"));
```

I have also tried parsing the URI to a bitmap but i can't get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

You may not want to use setImageURI - as the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageURI(android.net.Uri)) points out, this will decode the image on the UI thread, which is usually not a good idea.

Depending on the rest of the context, I'd suggest using an AsyncTask to load the file into a Bitmap on a separate thread, then after that is done, you can use ImageView.setImageBitmap on the UI thread.

So for example, something like this:

```
private class ImageLoadTask extends AsyncTask<Uri, Void, Bitmap> {
    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Uri... uris) {
        return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(uris[0].getPath());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bmp) {
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    }
}

...

mImageView = (TouchImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);
new ImageLoadTask.execute(uri);
```

Answer (score -1):

okay the answer was to parse it as a file and do a .toString()

**This is the code that works:**

```
TouchImageView img = (TouchImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
    img.setImageURI(Uri.parse((new File("file://storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camer/1411724483755.jpg").toString())));
```